# CS0079: The event 'CheckBox.CheckedChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a dilemma in C# that is giving me build errors.

I have a CheckBox (a MaterialSwitch to be exact) in my WinForms application that I want to set the theme to DARK when it is on, and LIGHT when it is off. This is my code:

```cs
public bool dark = true;
        
public Form1
{
  InitializeComponent();
  var materialSkinManager = MaterialSkinManager.Instance;
  if (materialSwitch1.CheckedChanged)
  {
     if (dark == true)
     {
       materialSkinManager.Theme = MaterialSkinManager.Themes.DARK;
     }
     else if (dark == false)
     {
       materialSkinManager.Theme = MaterialSkinManager.Themes.LIGHT;
     }
  }
  materialSkinManager.AddFormToManage(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [CheckedChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) is an [event](https://CheckedChanged) fired whenever the checkbox's state is changed. I believe you're looking for the property, `Checked`. You would need to subscribe to the event to capture when `materialSwitch1` is checked/unchecked.

You can subscribe to the event like this:

```cs
public Form1
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Subscribe to CheckedChanged event
    materialSwitch1.CheckedChanged += MaterialSwitch1_CheckedChanged;
}

public void MaterialSwitch1_CheckedChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    // Check if switch is checked
    if (materialSwitch1.Checked)
    {
        // Dark Mode
    }
    else
    {
        // Light Mode
    }
}
```

Place your theme-changing code within the `MaterialSwitch1_CheckedChanged` method.

Comment: I wanted the theme to change immediately when the switch toggle was changed.

Comment: @nickpythonluajava You would need to subscribe to the CheckedChanged event and run your code within the delegate/method provided to the event.  [Events In C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events)

Comment: @SkylerGhostly You should update your answer to explain this.